# timing a mutex,unsynchronized threads, and a semaphore in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, mutex, semaphore

I have an assignment where I am tasked to write a program in c# that will test out 5 different functions.   I seem to be having problems because it seems like my output for the timing of these tests is wrong (i.e they are always returning 0ms back). Also, my unsynced threads are always returning back the full value of 5000 when they should not be doing that all the time, what am I doing wrong with test #2 and Am I stopping the timer in the wrong area? Threading is kind of messing with my mind at this point and I would like to have some clarification on the matter... Below is the spec and my code...

**Test #1**: Will be an increment (basic) to the value 5000.

**Test #2**:  The main thread will create 10 threads that will increment the shared integer 500 times each.  You will not use any synchronization to protect the updating of the shared integer.  It is likely that the unsynchronized access to the shared integer will cause it to have an incorrect final value (<5000).

**Test #3**:  The main thread will create 10 threads that will increment the shared integer 500 times each.  You will protect the updating of the shared integer using a mutex.

**Test #4**:  The main thread will create 10 threads that will increment the shared integer 500 times each.  You will update the shared integer using the Increment method of the Interlocked class.

**Test #5**:  The main thread will create 10 threads that will increment the shared integer 500 times each.  You will protect the updating of the shared integer using a semaphore.

- Each test will be timed using the Stopwatch class and the total time the test took will be written to the console.
- Use Thread.Sleep() to simulate a random amount of processing time and assume the shared integer is being used at that time.
- Random time should be a random value between 0 and 10ms.

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Diagnostics;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Threading;

  namespace Lab3
  {
      class MainClass
      {
      public static int sharedVal = 0;
      public static int y = 1;
      static Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
      private static Mutex mutex = new Mutex();
      private static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1);


      public static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("***************** Lab 3 Thread/Synchronization Testing *****************" + "\n");
          Console.WriteLine("Starting Test 1 (no Threads)...");
          test1();
          Console.WriteLine("***************** Lab 3 Thread/Synchronization Testing *****************" + "\n");
          Console.WriteLine("Starting Test 2 (Threads without any synchronization)...");
          test2(10);
          Console.WriteLine("***************** Lab 3 Thread/Synchronization Testing *****************" + "\n");
          Console.WriteLine("Starting Test 3 (Threads with a mutex)...");
          test3(10);
          Console.WriteLine("***************** Lab 3 Thread/Synchronization Testing *****************" + "\n");
          Console.WriteLine("Starting Test 4 (Interlocked Methods)...");
          test4(10);
          Console.WriteLine("***************** Lab 3 Thread/Synchronization Testing *****************" + "\n");
          Console.WriteLine("Starting Test 5 (Threads with a semaphore)...");
          test5(10);

      }
      /*****************************************************************************/
      public static void test1()
      {
          timer.Reset();
          timer.Start();
          intChanger(ref sharedVal, 5000,0);
          Console.WriteLine("Test Complete");
          timer.Stop();
          Console.WriteLine("Shared Value: {0}, Total time: {1}ms ", sharedVal, timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);

          clearSharedVal(ref sharedVal);
      }
      /*****************************************************************************/
      public static void test2(int numOfThreads)
      {
          timer.Reset();
          timer.Start();
          threadCreate(numOfThreads);
          Console.WriteLine("Test Complete");
          Console.WriteLine("Shared Value: {0}, Total time: {1}ms ", sharedVal, timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
          clearSharedVal(ref sharedVal);
          y++;
      }
      /*****************************************************************************/
      public static void test3(int numOfThreads)
      {
          timer.Reset();
          timer.Start();
          threadCreate(numOfThreads);
          Console.WriteLine("Test Complete");
          Console.WriteLine("Shared Value: {0}, Total time: {1}ms ", sharedVal, timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
          clearSharedVal(ref sharedVal);
          y++;
      }
      /*****************************************************************************/
      public static void test4(int numOfThreads)
      {
          timer.Reset();
          timer.Start();
          threadCreate(numOfThreads);
          Console.WriteLine("Test Complete");
          Console.WriteLine("Shared Value: {0}, Total time: {1}ms ", sharedVal, timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
          clearSharedVal(ref sharedVal);
          y++;
      }
      /*****************************************************************************/
      public static void test5(int numOfThreads)
      {
          timer.Reset();
          timer.Start();
          threadCreate(numOfThreads);
          Console.WriteLine("Test Complete");
          Console.WriteLine("Shared Value: {0}, Total time: {1}ms ",sharedVal, timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
          clearSharedVal(ref sharedVal);
      }
      /*****************************************************************************/
      public static void threadCreate(int n)
      {
          Thread[] threadArr = new Thread[n];
          for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
          {
              threadArr[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WorkThreadFunction));
              threadArr[i].Start();              
          }
          //join for loop
          for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
          {
              threadArr[i].Join();
          }
          Console.WriteLine("All Threads have been joined");
          timer.Stop();
      }
      /******************************************************************************/
      public static void WorkThreadFunction()
      {
          switch (y) { 
              case 1:
                  intChanger(ref sharedVal, 500, 1);
                  break;
              case 2:
                  intChanger(ref sharedVal, 500, 2);
                  break;
              case 3:
                  intChanger(ref sharedVal, 500, 3);
                  break;
              case 4:
                  intChanger(ref sharedVal, 500, 4);
                  break;
          }
      }

      /*****************************************************************************/
    public static void intChanger(ref int s, int n , int flag)
    {
      /*******************************************************************************
      *                            Flag Explanation                                  *
      ********************************************************************************
      *    int flag = 0 --> unsynchronized single thread adding to shared value      *
      *    int flag = 1 --> unsynchronized threads adding to shared value            *
      *    int flag = 2 --> synchronized using a mutex                               *
      *    int flag = 3 --> synchronized using Increment method of Interlocked class *
      *    int flag = 4 --> synchronized using semaphore                             *
      ********************************************************************************/

          Random rand = new Random();

          switch (flag)
          {
              case 0:
                  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                  {
                      s++;
                  }

                  break;

              case 1:
                  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                  {
                      s++;
                  }
                  timer.Stop();
                  break;

              case 2:
                  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                  {
                      mutex.WaitOne();
                      Thread.Sleep(rand.Next(0, 10));
                      s++;
                      mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                  }
                  break;

              case 3:
                  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                  {
                      //Thread.Sleep(rand.Next(0, 10) * 1000);
                      Interlocked.Increment(ref s);
                  }
                  timer.Stop();
                  break;

              case 4:
                  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                  {
                      semaphore.WaitOne();
                      Thread.Sleep(rand.Next(0, 10));
                      s++;
                      semaphore.Release();
                  }
                  break;
          }
      }
          /*****************************************************************************/
          public static void clearSharedVal(ref int n)
      {
          n = 0;
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: For 2: The thread will have finished its loop, before you call thread[i].Start() again,
 increase your n to 1_000_000 and it will finish with something smaller than 10m.

Comment: be aware that you're also measuring thread startup time AND sleep time. im not sure what your goal is, but if you want to measure locking time, then you should keep that in mind. Thread startup time is up to 30ms, your loop is probably 0.0001 ms

Comment: Well I am tying to measure the length of time the whole test takes from the moment its initiated to the time it stops.

Answer (score 2):

Well, 5000 increments is a pretty simple task for a modern PC, so 0ms is expected for me. Try to increase a number of operations, or compare ElapsedTicks instead of ElapsedMilliseconds.
About #2. Creation of a new Thread is a heavy task, and the job itself is a light task. So, probably, to the time the next thread is ready to run, the previous one already finishes. They are running serially, not in parallel. You may again increase the number of operations, and use [threadpool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem?view=netframework-4.8) methods to run the job.

Edit:

Keep a note, that [Thread.Sleep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=netframework-4.8) method works not as you may expect for very low delays (below 15-20ms): `If dwMilliseconds is less than the resolution of the system clock, the thread may sleep for less than the specified length of time`.

Comment: Yup, with a 3GHz processor, assuming for simplicity sake, a scalar processor. Increment, if and goto will use about 3 clocks cycles call it 10. Multiply by 5000, gives 50 000 clocks. Divide by 3GHz, gives 10us or 0.01ms.